# Hiding nth-child of a specific table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, css-selectors

I have two tables on a page.  How do I address the second one, `id="tapp"`, to run show/hide nth-child functions?

I've ignorantly tried to address the particular table by adding the id reference to the beginning of `'td:nth-child...'`

```
...
var x = document.getElementById("tatt");
$(x.'td:nth-child(3),th:nth-child(3)').hide();
...
```

Comment: Are you hide nth-child of 3 in each row?

Comment: The overall idea is to have buttons that hide entire columns of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can precede the selector by *id* in each comma separated group. Try

```
$('#tatt td:nth-child(3), #tatt th:nth-child(3)').hide();
```

**Note:** Why you are using `getElementById()` when you already have jQuery?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought the 'ignorant' comment would be enough to explain ;)

Comment: Sorry, quick follow up: Would I be able to hide based on <td id = 'math'>, instead of 'nth'?

Comment: @sukebe7, in that case specify the *id* like `td#math`.... try `$('#tatt td#math, #tatt th:nth-child(3)').hide();`

Comment: @sukebe7, one more thing, I guess using *id* in *td* like that could give some unexpected result. Instead, you should use *class* to identify multiple elements....

Comment: I was able to build the buttons dynamically, along with the PHP-generated table.  So far, the nth method is working.  However, I should future-proof it with your suggestion, later.  - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather something like

```
$('#tatt').find('td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(3)').hide();
```

or

```
$('#tatt td:nth-child(3), #tatt th:nth-child(3)').hide();
```

(BTW, if you're using jQuery for DOM manipulation, there's really no need to call the `findElementById` method, too. Just stick to `$(/*selector*/)`.